# There is no service for type has been registered Exception coming in Blazor server side application

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

This is Razor form code

```
@inherits OwningComponentBase<SignatureColoursServices>
```

List Displaydata=new List();

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Displaydata = Service.GetSignatures();
}
```

This is the code in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISignatureColoursServices,SignatureColoursServices>();
```

This is `SignatureColour.cs`

```
public string Value { get; set; } = null!;

public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
```

This is `signaturecolourservices.cs`:

```
protected readonly MyDbContext _dbcontext;

public SignatureColoursServices(MyDbContext db)
{
    _dbcontext = db;
}

public List<SignatureColour> GetSignatures()
{
    return _dbcontext.SignatureColours.ToList();
}
```

I have tried adding singleton and transient and scoped in `startup.cs`

Answer (score 0):

You needed to register the service properly. Register `SignatureColourServices` in the **Program.cs** file. Please check the below example.

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<SignatureColourServices>();
```